# Bush-shirts rate

Tags: sentence-meaning

Sentence from "God of small things" after character ( baby kochamma) became obese.

"Even timid little chellappen tailor insisted on charging bush-shirts rates for her sari blouses."

Does it mean he charged less for I think Bush shirts are not attractive or proper (googled).or its the other way around?

Comment: Well, I think this might require a little too much subject-specific knowledge for me. The question I would ask is, what would you expect, at whatever time the book is set, to cost more - a bush shirt or a sari blouse? Which has more work go into it, which uses more fabric?

Comment: He's making larger sari blouses, surely must be charging more.

Comment: A Blouse uses less material than a shirt but its material is more expensive than shirt's, I think

Comment: Oh, I think I got it now.

Comment: Blouse had equivalent amount of material used as that needed for a shirt.

Comment: Although I don't understand the meaning of that sentence, I know that *even timid little chellappen tailor* is ungrammatical. There needs to be an article, or other kind of identifier, in front of *timid*. I also believe that the adjective should be *bush-shirt* (singular). Finally, I suspect that it should be *Chellappen*, with a capital *C*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This comic and accompanying text](https://litbrick.com/comic.php?date=2012-07-24) appear to give some context to work out what is being said, short of actually finding a copy of the book.

> Two years later, Baby Kochamma returned from Rochester [...] There was no trace of the slim, attractive girl that she had been [...] Baby Kochamma had grown extremely large. In fact, let it be said, obese. Even timid little Chellappen Tailor [...] insisted on charging bush-shirt rates for her sari blouses.

A bush-shirt is a loose fitting shirt worn in the 'bush', or the top half of a '[safari suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_jacket)'. It was an item for men (so larger) and used a lot of material compared with a blouse on pockets, epaulettes, and extra length that allowed it to be tied with a belt.

I wasn't sure if he meant the tailor charged less or more either, but on reflection, I am sure he means the tailor charged more than the standard price for a blouse because of the amount of material he had to use.